# VPN solution for connecting two locations with server in the third one

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

I want to connect two locations (two houses) with VPN connection. I want all networking devices (computers, printers etc) from location 1 (L1) to be able to communicate with location 2 (L2). I don't have public IP in any of the locations (all traffic is being NATed and I want to keep it that way) so I need to use a VPN server in other location and my idea was to use GCP (just my preference).

I want everything to look like this:

[image]

The trick is - that the VPN server will be used only to establish connection between the L1 and L2 sites.
Additionally I want all the traffic between L1 & L2 to go directly between them and not to GCP (they charge for the outgoing traffic and I want to keep to costs to minimum).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You will need to deploy your own VPN solution. Google Cloud VPN requires compatible hardware devices wich require public IP addresses. I have setup Wireguard on a VM which routes L1 <-> L2. However, that is an expensive solution at $0.12 per GB. Some home routers support port forwarding. You can then use the router's public IP address for one side of Wireguard to directly connect your home's networks together provided they do not have overlapping networks (warning, most use the same CIDR).

Comment: That public IP address might change periodically (mine does every 30 days) so you will need to reconfigure Wireguard each time. If available, the cheapest and easiest solution is to pay for a static IP address for one side.

Comment: I just want GCP as a platform to run the VPN server on - however I want to avoid sending any unnecessary traffic to this VM due to egress charges. I have static IP's on the outside so I can "hardcode" them at least for now.

Comment: There is no solution that I am aware of that meets your objectives. Private IP addresses cannot talk to each other without a man in the middle.

Comment: Exactly - and I want to be that middle point to be GCP VM.  I'm convinced I saw such solution but can't find it. Still looking though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try TailScale, which is *free for personal use*.

You can get it on Github,  [tailscale](https://github.com/tailscale) / [**tailscale**](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale):

> Private WireGuard® networks made easy
>
> #### Overview
>
> This repository contains all the open source Tailscale client code and the tailscaled daemon and tailscale CLI tool. The tailscaled daemon runs on Linux, Windows and macOS, and to varying degrees on FreeBSD, OpenBSD, and Darwin. (The Tailscale iOS and Android apps use this repo's code, but this repo doesn't contain the mobile GUI code.)